# How to copy class variable and call in another file

Tags: c++

In my main.cpp

```
void MainWindow::onFinish( ImageResult* result )
m_ImageIdResult = *result;
m_Result = m_ImageResult.AllMetadata;
```

Now I want to use the m_Result in my another display.cpp file. How do I copy the m_result so that I can use it in the other file. I tried the following as I have m_Display in header file of display.h

```
m_DisplayModel->howtodefinethisfunction(m_Result, asset-> );
```

I am sorry for this basic question, I have been unlucky with it and spent 2 days figuring it out.
Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to simply pass it as a function parameter:

```
some_func_in_display_cpp_file(m_Result, /* other parms ... */);
```

and define the function as:

```
return_type some_func_in_display_cpp_file(const m_result_type&, /* ... */) {
```

Answer (score 0):

A function parameter is the easiest way to pass it. I'm not sure what you're doing here:

```
m_DisplayModel->howtodefinethisfunction(m_Result, asset-> );
```

For the second parameter, you seem to have a pointer pointing to nothing. That will give you a compile error. But if you want the exact syntax of how to define the function, if you have m_Result declared in the MainWindow class like this:

```
CoolResult m_Result;
```

Then you would declared the function in DisplayModel like this:

```
public:
void DoSomethingWithResult( CoolResult result );
```

Then you would call it from your MainWindow class like this:

```
void MainWindow::onFinish( ImageResult* result )
m_ImageIdResult = *result;
m_Result = m_ImageResult.AllMetadata;

// this will probably be declared somewhere else in real code
DisplayModel display;
display.DoSomethingWithResult( m_Result );
```

But if what you want is to get result in DisplayModel from MainWindow, you'll create a getter in MainWindow (MainWindow.h):

```
public:
CoolResult GetResult();
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
CoolResult MainWindow::GetResult()
{
    return m_Result;
}
```

Hope this helps. If this doesn't cover your question, please include more details.